# SQL Error: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, where-clause

I want to display the data based on the date I selected, [fnDateTxtToWeekNum] will return the weeknum of the date I selected, weeknum is a parameter of [fnBenchmarkData], all available weeknum info stored in the dbo.Weeks table.

I am getting this error:

> "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 32)."

```
SELECT  p.weeknum, p.date, q.ID, q.score
FROM dbo.Weeks AS p 
cross apply
[dbo].fnBenchmarkData(p.weeknum) as q 
where weeknum = [dbo].[fnDateTxtToWeekNum]('2015-07-02')
```

Was it because I referenced weeknum twice and have the function calling it self? The @weeknum on fnBenchmarkData is referencing dbo.weeks (basically if without where clause, this SQL will return all data for all weeks). Then I use fnDateTxtToWeeknum, it will return a weeknumber, basically I create a filter so the SQL will only display the data of that specific week I need (convert date I entered to a weeknum).

/* I need the final output has both weeknum, date, ID, and score. The fnBenchmarkData will NOT return weeknum and date infomation by itself, that's why I need to use cross apply. */

Comment: Pretty sure by having the function call itself, you've set up an infinite loop, unless there's some part of the code you're not showing that would break the loop.

Comment: @TabAlleman It doesn't make any sense, the last line if I just use where weeknum = 777, the SQL will return the data only for week 777. The only change I made was add a function to convert the date I entered to 777, still not get why it is infinite loop.

Comment: impossible to tell from the snippet you have posted.   You need to post the full code for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the issue might reside inside the function.  Are you using recursion inside the function? If you are you might consider using a while-loop to get rid of it.  Looks like you have a recursive issue here.